# How to scan your code for deprecations or worse

Tags: node.js

We have this 'old' module (A) that still uses Promise.defer() and gets built with node v6. This module is used by a different module (B) that is used by even another module (C) that is being built with node v8.

Only in some code paths the defer is actually being called, so this is really a tricky run-time problem.

Ideally, I would just be notified by npm install that we're using obsolete code (from module C or B), but apparently it doesn't work that way. One can specify in the package.json (in module A) that the engine should be node v6 and release a new version, but that doesn't help for current modules (B and C) using the old version.

Is there a way to recursively scan for this sort of thing? Yes, I can do npm install, and then do some recursive grep for this specific Promise.defer thing, but I'd like to know if there are any generic tools for deprecated or obsolete code. I tried googling to no avail.

edit:

Using npm-check (suggested below and in the comments), I get a report on what packages have updates, are unused, and more. A bit similar to [depcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck), but npm-check looks more advanced.

Both of them can't detect that the V8 (v5.4) bundled with node 8 doesn't ship with Promise.defer ([this commit](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/fa160602a3b6703df1444d3bc463b60859b0f63e) unships that feature).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check

Comment: you might want to look into https://github.com/apps/greenkeeper

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated

Comment: Hey @Jan, Did you check my answer below? Was it any helpful?

Comment: Hey @CaptainJackSparrow, I just checked (sorry for the delay), and added a comment. It's starting to look like there's no tool that can be bothered about whether your code is compatible with the V8 engine bundled with node.

Comment: Oh, seems like we have a problem then, does my answer did help in any way?

Comment: Not really for the problem at hand, no. Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the **[npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)** package is a great solution.

Once it's installed, simply type `npm-check` to see what's out of date and what can be updated.
There are plenty of features available, like `npm-check -u` which provides an interactive method of updating each package.

Here's the full list of options available ...

```
Usage
  $ npm-check <path> <options>

Path
  Where to check. Defaults to current directory. Use -g for checking global modules.

Options
  -u, --update          Interactive update.
  -y, --update-all      Uninteractive update. Apply all updates without prompting.
  -g, --global          Look at global modules.
  -s, --skip-unused     Skip check for unused packages.
  -p, --production      Skip devDependencies.
  -d, --dev-only        Look at devDependencies only (skip dependencies).
  -i, --ignore          Ignore dependencies based on succeeding glob.
  -E, --save-exact      Save exact version (x.y.z) instead of caret (^x.y.z) in package.json.
  --specials            List of depcheck specials to include in check for unused dependencies.
  --no-color            Force or disable color output.
  --no-emoji            Remove emoji support. No emoji in default in CI environments.
  --debug               Show debug output. Throw in a gist when creating issues on github.

Examples
  $ npm-check           # See what can be updated, what isn't being used.
  $ npm-check ../foo    # Check another path.
  $ npm-check -gu       # Update globally installed modules by picking which ones to upgrade.
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check

---

In addition (since I'm not 100% certain what you're asking) ...

If you need to find out what the dependencies are for a particular package, you can use `npm la <package-name>` or `npm ll <package-name>`.
This will provide a [logical dependency tree](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls), based on package dependencies.

---

Of course, as with any depreciated support, the `Promise.defer()` will just have to be updated manually to the `new Promise(resolve, reject)` method.

Comment: `npm-check` does not perform checks at the fine-grained level that the OP describes in the question.

Comment: @Louis -- I added some additional information to hopefully cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [npm-outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated)

**This is provided by npm-cli**

```
npm outdated [[<@scope>/]<pkg> ...]
```

This command will check the registry to see if any (or, specific) installed packages are currently outdated

In the output:

- **wanted** is the maximum version of the package that satisfies the semver range specified in package.json. If there's no available semver range (i.e. you're running npm outdated --global, or the package isn't included in package.json), then wanted shows the currently-installed version.
- **latest** is the version of the package tagged as latest in the registry. Running npm publish with no special configuration will publish the package with a dist-tag of latest. This may or may not be the maximum version of the package, or the most-recently published version of the package, depending on how the package's developer manages the latest dist-tag.
- **location** is where in the dependency tree the package is located. Note that npm outdated defaults to a depth of 0, so unless you override that, you'll always be seeing only top-level dependencies that are outdated.
  package type (when using --long / -l) tells you whether this package is a dependency or a devDependency. Packages not included in package.json are always marked dependencies.
- **Red** means there's a newer version matching your semver requirements, so you should update now.
- **Yellow** indicates that there's a newer version above your semver requirements (usually new major, or new 0.x minor) so proceed with caution.

An example

```
$ npm outdated
Package      Current   Wanted   Latest  Location
glob          5.0.15   5.0.15    6.0.1  test-outdated-output
nothingness    0.0.3      git      git  test-outdated-output
npm            3.5.1    3.5.2    3.5.1  test-outdated-output
local-dev      0.0.3   linked   linked  test-outdated-output
once           1.3.2    1.3.3    1.3.3  test-outdated-output
```

With these dependencies:

```
{
  "glob": "^5.0.15",
  "nothingness": "github:othiym23/nothingness#master",
  "npm": "^3.5.1",
  "once": "^1.3.1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't check for the Promise.defer issue, but it is also an interesting tool.

Comment: Was it any helpful?

Comment: It helps to point out which packages can be updated, so in a certain sense yes. But it's not what I was looking for in the first place.